# trying to see how long a Lua script takes to finish executing

Tags: performance, time, lua

I'm trying to make my Lua script tell me how long it took until the entire script was executed, for improvement reasons

I've tried using functions like `os.clock()`, `os.time()` and `os.difftime()` in countless ways over the internet to achieve this result but they always return `0` at the end. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Your script is too fast :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it's a very small script, but there would be some way for me to collect the milliseconds?

Comment: Can you share the script in question? Or examples of you attempts with the `os` functions.

Comment: Does it need to be within Lua? On Unix, you could do `time lua script.lua`

Comment: @Nifim i'm trying to create a Lua course on udemy for a specific game, and i want to create an optimization topic, where i show how to optimize Lua scripts, making them faster and lighter, but i need to show the difference between two scripts being run with and without optimization, displaying the time it takes to run the entire script and in milliseconds (on Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
local before = os.clock()

for i=1,1e6 do
   local double = i*2
end

local after = os.clock()

print(string.format("Loop took %0.6f seconds to run", after - before)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the interval is too short, then just run the fragment multiple times until you arrive at a meaningful performance number.

For instance, Python's `timeit`'s `autorange` functionality runs the function to be timed as many times as it takes for the benchmark to take at least two seconds.

That way you'll arrive at two numbers; `n`, how many iterations of the code you actually ran, and `t`, the time (seconds) it took to run them. `n / t` will then be iterations per second, and `t / n * 1000` milliseconds per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Note that os.clock is not precise enough for very short statements/scripts.
That's why it's good to run the code multiple times as DarkWiiPlayer has pointed out.
If you want to talk about optimization then, then we need to mention profiling.
A while ago I made a profiler using pure Lua and you are welcome to use that:
https://bitbucket.org/itraykov/profile.lua/src/master/
When profiling you get to see which parts of the code took the longest time to execute.